# Hide reoccurring meetings in outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

Is there a way to hide reoccurring meetings in outlook?

Basically I have a bunch of reoccurring meetings that show up in my calendar.  But they make the one-off meeting less obvious ... which are usually more important.

Comment: What version of outlook?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to hide them entirely, but it should achieve the goal of making the one-off meetings more prominent to color code them differently.  (In Outlook 2003, right click on a calendar entry and select "label".)

Outlook also has the ability to set a rule that would automatically apply a color label based on meeting certain conditions.  I don't think the fact that a meeting recurs is one of the conditions, but perhaps other criteria about those meetings are sufficiently consistent for an automatic rule to work (for example, the identity of the organizer).